# Apache Camel sync multiple consumer

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a two instance of tomcat server running same web application due to durability.

These web applications consume some queue/topic form ActiveMQ using Apache-camel lib.

My issue is how to sync these two consumer so that only one consumer can get a particular message.I mean ActiveMQ send different message on each node.

Comment: Have you looked at the `master:` component?

Answer (score 1):

If your have two consumers subscribe to the same queue/topic, you can use selector to make sure only one consumer can get a particular message. You can find some explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828653/jms-how-do-message-selectors-work-with-multiple-queue-and-topic-consumers)

Camel [JMS component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) has the selector option could be use.